# Blazor server, copy to clipboard is failing in Safari

Tags: javascript, c#, blazor, clipboard, blazor-server-side

I added some simple functionality to copy a link to the clipboard, it works fine in Edge and Chrome but is failing in Safari with the following error:

*The request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied permission.*

I believe this is because Safari wants you to do it via the click event and Blazor is routing the request through it's interop layer.

Has anyone got this to work?

Sample code:

Razor:

```
<button title="Copy link to clipboard" @onclick="@(e=> CopyToClipboard("someText"))">Copy</button>
```

C#:

```
        private async Task CopyToClipboard(string textToCopy)
        {
            await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("navigator.clipboard.writeText", textToCopy);
        }
```

I had the javascript call in a separate javascript file, in a function, but was getting the same result.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to solve this. Instead of calling the javascript function to copy to the clipboard via Blazor interop, I just used the native button onclick and that solved it.

```
<button  onclick="navigator.clipboard.writeText('some text to copy')">Copy Link</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Next code is a CopyButton.razor component which works on all browsers, IOS included, and gives some UI feedback to the user.
Using obtrusive inline javascript, it changes the copy icon during half a second while copying the required value to the clipboard.

```
<a href="#" class="CopyToClipboard"
   onclick="var el = this;
            el.classList.add('Copying');
            navigator.clipboard.writeText('@Value');
            setTimeout(function(){
               el.classList.remove('Copying');
               }, 500);"
@onclick:preventDefault>

    <div class="StandBy">
        <img src="CopyIcon.png"/>
    </div>

    <div class="Loader">
        <img src="LoaderIcon.png"/>
    </div>

</a>

@code {
    [Parameter] public string? Value { get; set; }

    //onclick description:
    //assign the anchor element to a variable since settimeout callback function loses the reference to "this"
    //add a class to give IU feedback to the user hidding the standard copy icon and showing a loader
    //write the value to clipboard. Due to IOS restrictions, Html native onclick event must be used instead of Blazor event.
    //add a delay in miliseconds with a callback function that removes the CSS class to hide the loader and display the standard copy icon again
}
```

And the Css style file CopyButton.razor.css:

```
.StandBy {
    display: inline-block;
}

.Loader {
    display:none;
}

.Copying .StandBy {
    display:none;
}

.Copying .Loader {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Usage sample page:

```
@page "/test"

<input type="text" @bind-value="value"/>

<CopyButton Value="@value"></CopyButton>

@code {
    string value = "sample string to copy";
}
```